# How to display attributes?

Tags: magento2, attributes

i'm using 2.2.X

How to get Stores > Attributes > Product > attributes code custom show to the Front-end and CMS Page.

look like `<? php echo:_('xxxx') ?>` 18n

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

In block file of your module, you have to create object of 
Magento\Catalog\Model\Product

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\YourModule\Block;

class Demo extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_product;

    public function __construct(Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    )
    {
        $this->_product = $product;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * GetProductObject Method to get product object.
     * @return object Product model object
     */
    public function getProductObject()
    {
        return $this->_product;
    }        
}
```

In your layout xml file add this code:

Vendor/YourModule/view/frontend/layout/frontname_index_index.xml (make appropriate name of layout xml file)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\YourModule\Block\Demo" name="name" template="Vendor_YourModule::name.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

In your name.phtml you can call these methods using this code.

Vendor/YourModule/view/frontend/templates/name.phtml

```
<?php
    $_product = $block->getProductObject();
?>
<?= $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('Attribute   Code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);  // To get Label value of dropdown option?>
<?= $_product->getAttributeCode(); // eg. $_product->getPrice()?>
```